# Secuirty risk when using ADMembershipProvider in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, security, active-directory

I using form based authentication with ADMembershipProvider for all of my ASP.NET application
with this connection string for LDAP lookup.

```
<add name="ADCN" connectionString="LDAP://dc01.mydomain.se" />
```

Is there any secuirty risk with this. Should i disable some system account or similar?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a security risk. I use the same connection string within my application and all is well. As far as I know, this is one of the only ways to use Active Directory and log in. Since it is in your web.config, no one should be able to see this connection string, therefore being pretty safe.